# Angular binding data-* attribute not working for methods

Tags: angularjs

I have this tag on my view

```
<div id="PeoplePickerDiv" 
             data-office-control="Office.Controls.PeoplePicker"
             data-office-options='{{optionsControlPicker}}'>
            Loading users...
        </div>
```

And this code on my controller

```
$scope.optionsControlPicker = {
    allowMultipleSelections: false,
    placeholder: "Find a user 123...",
    onChange: function (ctrl) { alert('cambie') }
}
```

This is the result

```
<div data-office-options="{"allowMultipleSelections":false,"placeholder":"Find a user 123..."}" ...
```

Angular is not rendering the onChange function. Is there a way to render that method as well?

It Should look like this

```
<div data-office-options="{
                "allowMultipleSelections" : false,
                "placeholder" : "Find a user ...",
                 "onChange" : function(ctrl){ alert("cambie") }   
            }" ....
```

Comment: Yes, it would not render function. You can do it. But how it should look like.

Comment: Please, see te edit

Comment: This question seems not well constructed. Do you mean to say that binding methods or functions to data-* attributes don't work, rather, it displays the function as a string.